# How to use Generic methods without passing Type Parameters when calling the generic method?

Tags: java, generics

I can understand and visualise in my head how this works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String passString = foo("hello");
    Integer passInteger = foo(5);
}
public static <K> K foo(K k) {
    return k;
}
```

Well the compiler knows K is String in first case and Integer in the second case, because we are passing the object as a parameter when calling foo.

But I can not understand how this works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> myMap
            = newInstance();
    myMap.put(1, "Hello");
}
public static <K,V> HashMap<K,V> newInstance() {
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

Does the compiler actually check what I assign myMap to? Is some sort of hidden casting going on here? Maybe I am missing something obvious, but how is K and V resolved at the compile time to be Integer and String?

Comment: One downvote, one answer, one favorite, one close vote.. Who is going to share, edit and flag?

Answer (score 3):

> Does the compiler actually check what I assign myMap to?

Yes, that's exactly what it does.  This is called [target type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) or "target typing".

It's worth noting that `javac`'s ability to make these kinds of inferences was improved in Java 8 -- there are now fewer places where you need to provide an explicit type witness (like `Collections.<String>emptySet()`).

Comment: What if I make the method like: newInstance(K k, V v) ? Is "target type inference" disabled in this situation?

Comment: No, it will still work.  For an example of that, see `Collections.singletonMap()`.

Comment: But why is it still required? I am already passing the objects, thus the types?

Comment: Why is what still required?  The type parameters on the left hand side (in `HashMap<Integer, String> myMap`)?  The short answer is "that's just the way the language is designed".